# Firebase Functions: Why do they sometimes fail? Why do they often complete without error but don't fulfill all tasks?

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-functions

This perplexes me. I'm six months into a firebase project and have been using Javascript for firebase-functions. I've learned a lot along the way by adding transactions, promises, batch writes and neat tricks. However, it seems like complete luck for a function to execute correctly. More often than not, the functions do execute correctly, but there are strange periods when bursts of consecutive function calls where functions half complete with no errors in the logs.

For example. I have a function for when a new user joins my app. It does a little bit of server data construction and also notifies the two admins that a new user has joined. Last night I did a test run with two new users and got no notification, but their user profiles constructed correctly on the server database. I checked the function logs and there were no errors.

Am I not handling Promises in the correct way? If a firebase function hangs, does it mess up the next few function calls?

```
exports.onNewUser = functions.firestore
    .document('/users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        user = snapshot.data().username;

        //Notification payload
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `New user!`,
                body: `${user} has joined [AppName]`
            }
        };
        var promises = [];
        //Check if usename unique
        var passed = true;
        promises.push(db.runTransaction(async t => {
            const docRef = db.collection('users').doc('index');
            const doc = await t.get(docRef);
            var newIndex = doc.data().usernames;
            if (newIndex[user.toUpperCase()] == true) {
                t.delete(snapshot.ref);
                passed = false;
                return null;
            } else {
                newIndex[user.toUpperCase()] = true;
                t.set(docRef, { 'usernames': newIndex });
            }
        }));
        if (!passed) return Promise.all(promises);

        //add new user to Algolia database
        const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
        const algoliaClient = algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.appid, functions.config().algolia.apikey);
        const collectionIndex = algoliaClient.initIndex(collectionIndexName);
        await saveDocumentInAlgolia(snapshot, collectionIndex);

        //Notify Admins
        db.collection('notificationTokens')
            .doc(admin1)
            .get().then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists && doc.data().notificationToken != null)
                    promises.push(pushNotification(doc.data().notificationToken, payload));
            });
        db.collection('notificationTokens')
            .doc(admin2)
            .get().then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists && doc.data().notificationToken != null)
                    promises.push(pushNotification(doc.data().notificationToken, payload));
            });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
```

Comment: From a quick glance, you are definitely not handling promises correctly throughout your code. It usually doesn't make sense to mix async/await with then/catch chains.  As much as possible, prefer await.

Comment: Interesting. I will make the switch immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
return Promise.all(promises);
```

to

```
return await Promise.all(promises);
```

You have to wait till the promises resolve before you return the function, as that would stop the instance of the cloud function.